Waterproofing the canvas what can I use?
What can I use to water proof the canvas on my antigen camper ? It is not leaking but I don’t want it to start

Not quite sure what 'antigen' means here. But, there are lots of canvas waterproofing products around. See what is in stock at your local  trailer/rv supply store and ask them what they would recommend.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is 'antigen' meant to be 'antique'?

A quick Google search turns up many products.  I've used linseed oil.
